# How can I get the ID of the clicked document and get the title and use/save it in firestore?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, onclicklistener

```
const setupProducts = (data) => {
  
    if (data.length) {
      let html = '';
      data.forEach(doc => {
        const product = doc.data();
        const li = `
          <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4"> ${product.title} </div>
            <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">  ${doc.id} </div>
            <div class="collapsible-body white"> ${product.content} 
            <a href="" class="secondary-content">
            <a class="btn orange modal-trigger" >Get ID</a>
            </a>
          </li>
        `;
        html += li;
      });
      productList.innerHTML = html
    } else {
      productList.innerHTML = '<h5 class="center-align">Login to view products</h5>';
    }
  };
```

My idea is that I want to get the ID by clicking on the document and then but the `product.title` in `db.collection('activeWorks').doc(doc.id or product.id (I don't know what's right...)).set`. I have no idea how to do this, please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this: set the `id` tag of each `<li>` element to the doc id from Firestore, then attach an `onclick` event trigger

```
  const setupProducts = (data) => {

if (data.length) {
  let html = '';
  productList.innerHTML = ''
  data.forEach(doc => {
    const product = doc.data();
    const li = `
      <li id="${doc.id}">
        <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4"> ${product.title} </div>
        <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">  ${doc.id} </div>
        <div class="collapsible-body white"> ${product.content} 
        <a href="" class="secondary-content">
        <a class="btn orange modal-trigger" >Get ID</a>
        </a>
      </li>
    `;
    html += li;
    productList.innerHTML += html
    document.getElementById(doc.id).onclick = () => {
        // do firestore stuff here
        // db.collection('activeWorks').doc(doc.id).set(your_data)
    }
  });
} else {
  productList.innerHTML = '<h5 class="center-align">Login to view products</h5>';
}
};
```

If I misunderstood your question I'm sorry

Comment: Tanks for your help if I try this there is always am error: "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"